# why <net/route.h> can be included and compiled in IOS6.1 simulator while cannot be compiled in actual iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I tried to include  to finish a gateway fetch problem. In xcode IOS simulator compiling process, it can be included, however in real IOS machine it can't. I can only put a copy of route.h in project and it really works in real machine. But this brings another problem in simulator. It says structs such as rt_metrics,rtstat are redefined, with an information:'Definition of 'struct rt_metricx' must be imported from module 'Darwin.net.route' before it is required'.
How can I do to solve this problem?
This is the header files I included in my file.

```
#include "route.h"
//#include <net/route.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>
#include "resolv.h"
```

Answer (score 3):

For some reason that header file only exist in the iOS Simulator SDK, but not iOS SDK.

You can put a copy of the header file in your project and conditionally include it for iOS.

--EDIT--

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#include <net/route.h>
#else
#include "route.h"
#endif
```

Comment: How exactly does one conditionally include a .h file based on IOS device versus simulator?

Comment: Is it okay if I have to publish the app on the app store? What  license do i need to comply if I'm using the route.h file as it is in my xcode project.

Answer (score 3):

I wrestled with this forever before realizing that if you `#import` both headers instead you don't even need to worry about the `#if` guard.

```
#import <net/route.h>
#import "route.h"
```

Comment: the best answer ever :)

Answer (score 3):

You can find the **route.h** file in **/usr/include/net** folder in your mac. Just copy it into your xcode project. it works ;)

Comment: dear i "copy rout.h" in my xcode project but still  xcode says not found,i cannot build my project,i am using xcode 10.1.please guide me about that what should i do for build it successfully thanks for shearing information