# 'pod lib lint' conflict between 'route.h' and <net/route.h>

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to run ***pod lib lint*** on a Cocoa Framework swift project and it returns the following error:

```
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  /MyProject/route.h:164:8: error: redefinition of 'rt_msghdr2'
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms
                             /iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk
                             /usr/include/net/route.h:164:8: 
                             note: previous definition is here
```

I have an Objective-C class (NetworkUtil.h - NetworkUtil.m) with the following import structure.

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#include <net/route.h>
#else
#include "route.h"
#endif
```

> This, because route.h file only exist in the iOS Simulator SDK, but not in the actual iOS SDK (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23411469/5973853). I check whether it is an iPhone simulator, so the original < net/route.h > will be imported, or it runs on an actual iPhone, in that case it gets my manually copied 'route.h'.

Xcode manages to build and run the whole project correctly, but xcodebuild used by ***pod lib lint*** doesn't. For some reason, it imports both < net/route.h > and 'route.h' without considering the *#if_TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR* validation and that makes the conflict due to "redefinition of several functions".

Is there any solution or workaround to this conflict?